# Exception in HostFunction: <unknown> when trying to push new screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

#### Issue Description

Trying to push a new screen with
`Navigation.push(this, {
            component: {
                name: 'awesome-places.AuthScreen' }})`

And getting an error `Exepction in HostFunction <unknown>`

[Error Screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/27829763/57028793-01f9c980-6c0e-11e9-893f-3fe7735645d6.png)

#### Steps to Reproduce / Code Snippets / Screenshots

Create RN app, install required modules (redux, react-redux, react-native-navigation, react-vector-icons) and run code on Android device.

Add relevant code, App.js and component that causes the error. I tried running Navigation.push with `this.props.componentId` but when I press the button there is no response

#### App.js

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import AuthScreen from './src/screens/Auth/Auth';
import SharePlaceScreen from './src/screens/SharePlace/SharePlace';
import FindPlaceScreen from './src/screens/FindPlace/FindPlace';
import PlaceDetailScreen from './src/screens/PlaceDetail/PlaceDetail';
import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

// Register Screens
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux("awesome-places.AuthScreen", () => AuthScreen, Provider, store);
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux("awesome-places.SharePlaceScreen", () => SharePlaceScreen, Provider, store);
Navigation.registerComponentWithRedux("awesome-places.FindPlaceScreen", () => FindPlaceScreen, Provider, store);
Navigation.registerComponent("awesome-places.PlaceDetailScreen", () => PlaceDetailScreen);

// Start an App
Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      component: {
        name: 'awesome-places.AuthScreen'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

#### FindPlace.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

import PlaceList from '../../components/PlaceList/PlaceList';

class FindPlaceScreen extends Component {
        Navigation.push(this, {
            component: {
                name: 'awesome-places.AuthScreen',
            }
        })

    }

    render () {
        return(
            <View>
                <PlaceList places={this.props.places} onItemSelected={this.itemSelectedHandler} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        places: state.places.places
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FindPlaceScreen);
```

---

#### Environment

- React Native Navigation version: 2.17.0
- React Native version: 0.59.4
- Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): Android
- Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): Android 7.1.2, Debug

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're pushing the screen with `this` instead of an explicit `componentId`.
When calling `Navigation.push`, the first argument needs to be a componentId. See the [docs for reference](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/screen-api?id=pushcomponentid-layout).

Also, this might not be a problem, but `registerComponentWithRedux` is deprecated and you should register the screen with the [new api](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/top-level-api-migration?id=registering-screens-with-wrapping-provider-component)

Comment: I already tried passing `this.props.componentId` as an argument but that didn't have any effect